# Amazon SQS to funnel database writes

Tags: mysql, queue, scale, amazon-sqs

Assume I am building netflix and I want to log each view by the userID and the movie ID

The format would be viewID , userID, timestamp,

However in order to scale this, assume were getting 1000 views a second. Would it make sense to queue these views to SQS and then our queue readers can un-queue one by one and write it to the mysql database. This way the database is not overloaded with write requests.

Does this look like something that would work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Faisal,

This is a reasonable architecture; however, you should know that writing to SQS is going to be many times slower than writing to something like RabbitMQ (or any local) message queue.

By default, SQS FIFO queues support up to 3,000 messages per second with batching, or up to 300 messages per second (300 send, receive, or delete operations per second) without batching. To request a limit increase, you need to file a support request.

That being said, starting with SQS wouldn't be a bad idea since it is easy to use and debug.

Additionally, you may want to investigate MongoDB for logging...check out the following references:

**MongoDB is Fantastic for Logging**

http://blog.mongodb.org/post/172254834/mongodb-is-fantastic-for-logging

**Capped Collections**

http://blog.mongodb.org/post/116405435/capped-collections

**Using MongoDB for Real-time Analytics**

http://blog.mongodb.org/post/171353301/using-mongodb-for-real-time-analytics

Comment: Thank you so much! The links are great.

Comment: FYI, I would no longer recommend MongoDB for logging. Now, I'd likely use something more kafka-esque and potentially use multiple stream consumer-processors. One of those processors should be a backup of the entire history of the stream in order to make it easy to replay.

Comment: @WilMooreIII: After so many years, does this architecture still hold? Better to write to SQS and finish that operation there (hence make it short)? And have a separate process read from SQS and write to the dB?

Comment: @Rohitesh: IMO, I would still personally prefer kafka; however, SQS would be fine as well.

Comment: @WilMooreIII Actually, my question was, does this structure still make sense? If I have a high traffic app with dB writes, am I really increasing throughput by writing to a queue and then having a separate process to read from that queue and write to dB, or better to write to dB directly in the first place? (if you'd prefer, I can put this as a separate question instead of spamming this comment thread)

Comment: @Rohitesh New question would be best so others can chime in as well.